# How do I make RFT report test results in real time?

Tags: teamcity, rft

In our development environment, we run a Continuous Integration service (TeamCity) which responds to code checkins by running build/test jobs and reporting the results.  While the job is in progress, we can easily see how many unit tests have executed so far, how many have failed, etc.

My automated testing team is delivering UI tests developed in Rational Functional Tester.  Extracting those tests from the source control system, compiling them, and executing them from the command line all seem to be pretty straight forward exercises.

What I haven't been able to find is a way to report the test results automatically - there don't appear to be any hooks for listeners, for example, or any way to customize the messages that are emitted.

From my research thus far, I've come to the conclusion that my only option is to (a) wait until the tests finish, then (b) parse the HTML report that RFT generates.

Does anybody have a better answer than that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the workaround I've used for the similar purpose:

1. Write a helper super class that overwrite the onTerminate callback method, implement your log parsing logics there.
2. Change the helper super class of your test scripts to the helper super class create in step1.
3. Use [RFT CLI](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/run-scripts-through-the-rational-functional-tester-command-line/index.html#fig01) invoke your scripts in your Continous Integration code.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @eric2323223, in your onTerminate override, you can use TeamCity's [build script interaction](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD6/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity) functionality to have your RFT pass/fail status rolled up to TeamCity. You just need these TeamCity specific messages emitted to the command line, so that TeamCity picks them up.

```
##teamcity[testStarted name='test1']
##teamcity[testFailed name='test1' message='failure message' details='message and stack trace']
##teamcity[testFinished name='test1']

##teamcity[testStarted name='test2']
##teamcity[testFailed type='comparisonFailure' name='test2' message='failure message' details='message and stack trace' expected='expected value' actual='actual value']
##teamcity[testFinished name='test2']
```